# JAR files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\ext" not showing up in sulbimetext

Tags: java, sublimetext3

My external libraries are not showing up as existent in sublimeText3.

I have downloaded the apache commons math library into my

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_181\lib\ext"`

file and have tried to import it in sublime text using `"import org.apache.commons.math3"` but it is giving me the error: `"error: package org.apache.commons does not exist".`

I don't use an IDE so don't recommend I use one, I just want to know how to add libraries externally so that I can use them in java.

Comment: You're not supposed to do this. That directory isn't there for you to add arbitrary stuff into. It is there for the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime isn't an IDE, it's just a text editor. As such, all it can do is edit your files for you, and run external commands when you tell it to. The extent of the support for Java that's built into Sublime without external packages includes syntax highlighting Java source files (and all of the other features that entails, such as symbol lookups), the ability to compile a single `java` file to a `class` file, and the ability to execute an `ant` build.

So it's missing things like the ability to compile more than one `java` file, handle files that are a part of a package, or run the resulting program when you're done without more work on your end.

Or if you will, if you don't already know how to compile and run a Java program from a command prompt using raw Java tools, Sublime isn't going to be able to do that for you out of the box; it requires you to know enough to set it up for yourself.

Your overall problem sounds like you need to tell the Java compiler to add the `jar` file that you added to the `CLASSPATH` so that it knows to look inside. That's one of the things that dedicated Java IDE's help you with that Sublime will not.